# AjaxForm not working in Safari and Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

This javascript works in FF but not safari or Chrome:

```
$('#image').change(function() {
    $('#imageform').ajaxForm({
       target: '#preview',
       success: function() { 
          alert('works!');
       }
    }).submit();
});
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/ajaxImage/">
```

Please help me get it to work in Safari and Chrome!

EDIT:

I found my problem. I have a form inside a form, which prevents it from working. Thank you all for all of your suggestions.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What does your browser tool report?

Comment: It reports absolutely nothing. No POST requests and no javascript errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use the ajaxSubmit function, the code to send a POST a request:

```
$("#imageform").ajaxSubmit({
    url: 'ServerSidePage.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function() 
    { 
      alert("works!");
    }
});
```

EDIT:
might check this out also:

```
$('#imageform').ajaxForm({
  success: function(response, statusText) {
    $('#preview').html(response);
  }
});
```

i don't know what "#preview" is, might change it to "append" or whatever you need.

Comment: ok, this code is working fine, but maybe something goes wrong with your "/admin/ajaxImage/" can you show the server side code?

Comment: Is there a way for this to prompt the browser to save the password too?

Comment: having same issue; placing `ajaxSubmit()` solved the issue for me on chrome! I didn't test on safari or other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.ajaxForm()` sets up event listeners to handle submissions.
You should never call it more than once.

To use invoke the plugin by hand, call `ajaxSubmit()` instead.

For more information, see the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was totally different. I have a form inside a form, which prevents it from workings. Thank you for all the suggestions!